# Prolog programming - simple negative query

Tags: prolog

My database is:

```
eat(magi,limo).
eat(nona,banana).
```

How do I ask: "Who's not eating limo?" This:

```
eat(X,not(limo)).
```

Doesn't work. :(

Comment: You have a legit answer, you should mark it as answer or people will stop answering your questions in the future

Answer (score 8):

First of all `limo` is a symbol and you can't negate symbols. What you want to do is negate the predicate, i.e. `not(eat(X, limo))`.

However this still does not give you `nona` as a result. Why not? Well there are infinitely many values X for which `eat(X, limo)` will be false. The system needs more information than "X does not eat limo" to know which one you want. Instead we need to ask for an `X` such that "X eats something, but X does not eat limo". This leads us to the following query:

```
eat(X,Y), not(eat(X, limo)).
```

Which gives us `nona` as the solution for `X`.

Answer (score 0):

`eat(X, Y),  Y \= limo, writeln(X), false.`

Comment: The question was "Who does not eat limo?" while your query answers "Who eats anything other than limo?". I.e. if magi would eat limo and banana, it would be a solution for X in your query, but I don't think that that's what the OP wants.